# HaskellのIOアクションの取り扱いについて

Tags: haskell

Haskell初心者です。
質問なのですが、

```
parseDnsMessage :: BG.BitGet DnsMessage

recQuery :: BS.ByteString -> String -> IO BS.ByteString


resolveName :: [Word8] -> [Word8] -> BS.ByteString -> String
resolveName qname name bstr = do
  let newbstr = BSL.toStrict $ replace (BS.pack qname) (BS.pack name) bstr
  retbstr <- recQuery newbstr (head rootServers4)
  let msg = BG.runBitGet retbstr parseDnsMessage
  case msg of
    Right m -> (intercalate "." $ map show (rdata $ head $ answer $ m))
```

---以下エラーメッセージ---

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[BSI.ByteString]’
            with actual type ‘IO BSI.ByteString’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  retbstr <- recQuery newbstr (head rootServers4)
In the expression:
  do { let newbstr
             = BSL.toStrict $ replace (BS.pack qname) (BS.pack name) bstr;
       retbstr <- recQuery newbstr (head rootServers4);
       let msg = BG.runBitGet retbstr parseDnsMessage;
       case msg of {
         Right m
           -> (intercalate "." $ map show (rdata $ head $ answer $ m)) } }
```

このような場合どのように書くのが適切なのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

do 記法は、 `<-` によって中身を取り出しながら処理ができているように見えますが、制約があって、その do 記法全体が表す値は、中身を取り出されるモナドの型でなくてはいけません。

別の言葉で言うと、 IO の中身を `<-` で取り出して何かしらを記述する場合には、その結果も IO でないといけません。

なので、少なくとも resolveName は

```
resolveName :: [Word8] -> [Word8] -> BS.ByteString -> IO String
```

であるべきです。これを実現するのに、必要とされている関数は、 `String -> IO String`を実現する関数になるかと思います。これのためには、 [`return`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) が使えます。

最後の `intercalate` の戻り値を return に食わせて、正しそうな形へ変形していくと、欲しい物が得られるのではないでしょうか。